# php mail function with pdf attachment and html message

Tags: php, email, pdf, sendmail, email-attachments

I have an issue to send email with PDF attachment and message content is html format. Please checkout my below code. HTML email works fine. but the issue is in pdf attachment.

```
<?php
$random_hash = md5(date('r', time()));
$headers = "From: ".$from."\r\nReply-To: ".$from;
$headers .= "\r\nContent-Type: text/html; boundary=\"PHP-mixed-".$random_hash."\"";

foreach($summaryArray as $summaryArrayValue)
{
  $file  = 'pdf_directory/'.$summaryArrayValue['result_filename'].'.pdf';
  $fileName = $summaryArrayValue['result_filename'];

  $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($file)));
  $message.=<<<EOD
  Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name="{$fileName}" // tried with both application/octet-stream and application/pdf
  Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
  Content-Disposition: attachment

  {$attachment}
  --PHP-mixed-{$random_hash}--

EOD;
}

$mail_sent = mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
echo $mail_sent ? "Mail sent" : "Mail failed";
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the PHPMailer script it's easier option by a very large margin compared to trying to do it yourself with PHP's built-in mail() function. PHP's mail() function really isn't very good.

To use PHPMailer:

```
Download the PHPMailer script from here: http://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer
Extract the archive and copy the script's folder to a convenient place in your project.
Include the main script file -- require_once('path/to/file/class.phpmailer.php');
```

Now, sending emails with attachments goes from being insanely difficult to incredibly easy:

```
$email = new PHPMailer();
$email->From      = 'you@example.com';
$email->FromName  = 'Your Name';
$email->Subject   = 'Message Subject';
$email->Body      = $bodytext;
$email->AddAddress( 'destinationaddress@example.com' );

$file_to_attach = 'PATH_OF_YOUR_FILE_HERE';

$email->AddAttachment( $file_to_attach , 'NameOfFile.pdf' );

return $email->Send();
```

It's just that one line $email->AddAttachment(); -- you couldn't ask for any easier.

If you do it with PHP's mail() function, you'll be writing stacks of code, and you'll probably have lots of really difficult to find bugs.